# Issue with query in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working with Web API and ASP.NET MVC.

I'm passing a wrong username and password in the address bar then also give the success message that is the issue

[image]

This record is not available in my table:

[image]

I am creating 2 projects one for Web API framework scaffolding and second is a normal empty ASP.NET MVC project.

Normal empty ASP.NET MVC project (not using Entity Framework)

`globalvariable.cs`:

```
namespace Mvc
{
    public static class globalvariable
    {
        public static HttpClient webapiclient = new HttpClient();

        static globalvariable()
        {
            webapiclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:0000/api/");
            webapiclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            webapiclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    }
}
```

`empsController.cs`:

```
namespace Mvc.Controllers
{
    public class empsController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<mvcempmodel> empList;
            HttpResponseMessage response = globalvariable.webapiclient.GetAsync("emps").Result;
            empList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<mvcempmodel>>().Result;
            //return View(empList);
            return Json(empList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Login(string username, string password)
        {
                if (username == "" || username == null)
                {
                    var data = new
                    {
                        message = "Enter Username ",
                    };
                    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else if (password == "" || password == null)
                {
                    var data = new
                    {
                        message = "Enter Password",
                    };
                    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    var userdata = "select * from emp where username='" + username + "'and password='" + password + "'".First();
                    if (userdata != null)
                    {
                        var data = new
                        {
                            message = "Success",
                            data = new { username }
                        };
                        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var data = new
                        {
                            message = "Username and Password incorrect ",
                        };
                        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web API project (using Entity Framework)

`empsController.cs`:

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class empsController : ApiController
    {
        private empdbEntities db = new empdbEntities();

        // GET: api/emps
        public IQueryable<emp> Getemps()
        {
            return db.emps;
        }

        // GET: api/emps/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(emp))]
        public IHttpActionResult Getemp(int id)
        {
            emp emp = db.emps.Find(id);

            if (emp == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(emp);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to If user enter true credential then give the success message and when the user enter false credential then give the username and password incorrect message

Here I think my query is wrong

```
var userdata = "select * from emp where username='" + username + "'and password='" + password + "'".First();
```

Please help

Comment: You're a not querying a database, all you are doing is define a string. Moreover you are passing in username and password via the query string which is unsafe. You should also use a parametrized query rather than a replace

Comment: @OleEHDufour I am beginner how to querying a database, please help

Answer (score 0):

You can check this to url (as you mentioned you are a beginner and wanted to know how to query a database)

In asp.net, You can query a database using

1. Entity framework (the second link shows how to query local db using Entity framework)
2. Dapper (micro orm, fast)
3. ADO.net (old school style and required to write a lot of boiler plate code)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

To query Sql server database at remote or local server, just change the connection string.